# If $P$ is a prime ideal in a commutative ring $R$ with unity, and $\{P\}$ is closed under the Zariski topology on $\text{Spec}R$, then $P$ is maximal.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, solution-verification, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Here’s the statement I want to prove:

> If $P$ is a prime ideal in a commutative ring $R$ with unity, and $\{P\}$ is closed under the Zariski topology on $\text{Spec}R$, then $P$ is maximal.

Here, for an ideal $J$ of $R$, we define a closed subset to be
$$V(J):= \{P \in \text{Spec}R \ | \ P \supseteq J\}$$

I want to ask for opinions on my attempt below.

Assume for a contradiction that $P$ is not maximal. So $P$ can be enlarged, i.e., there exists $k \in R \setminus P$ such that $(k) + P \neq R$. In particular, $(k) + P$ is a proper ideal that is strictly larger than $P$. Let $J \subseteq P$, where $J$ is an ideal of $R$. Then $V(J) \ni(k) + P$, which implies there is no ideals $J$ of $R$ such that $V(J) = \{P\}$. Hence $\{P\}$ is not closed. $\Rightarrow$ Contradiction.

Comment: What do you even want to prove?

Comment: Your assertion $V(J) \supseteq (k) + P$ makes no sense. Also, singletons need not be closed in the Zariski topology.

Comment: The statement I want to prove is in the title. Also, I’ve just realized that I failed to check if $(k) + P$ is prime. I will need to revise the proof.

Comment: Even if you checked that $(k) + P$ was prime, it wouldn't make sense, you're looking for the symbol $\ni$. But putting that aside, this statement is wrong anyway, it is not necessarily prime (look for a counterexample!). Instead, you should recall a result about maximal ideals.

Comment: Please write your questions into the thread itself, not just into the title. As you can see, it leads to confusion (and is not a good choice for a title anyhow).

Comment: Hint for a proof: First, try to show that the closure of $\{P\}$ in Zariski topology is $V(P)$. Then the assumption that $\{P\}$ is closed gives $V(P)=\{P\}$ which then implies there are no prime ideals strictly larger than $P$. Using the fact that in a commutative ring with unity, every proper ideal is contained in a maximal ideal and a maximal ideal is necessarily prime, we obtain the desired result.